# Is there a way yet to configure mathjax for wordpress.com?

Tags: mathjax, wordpress.com

There is a plugin for wordpress.org. But is there a way to add some code to the page template in wordpress.com, like you can for blogger?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to add code into a Wordpress page; Wordpress is very flexible. Unfortunately, I left Wordpress years ago and can't give you concrete steps on how to do that. I moved my blog to [jekyl ( a static site generator ) hosted on github, which is much simpler](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Best-Blog-Platform-for-Writing-Mathematics)

Answer (score 2):

Searching "mathjax" on wordpress.com, I've found [this thread](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/mathjax?replies=4) useful. In the second post, it provides a [link](http://en.support.wordpress.com/latex/) to the official guide on LaTeX support, which you be helpful if you *just* need to typeset math on wordpress.com.